# Making Entries Accept decimal numbers only in python

Tags: python, tkinter

*I want to know how can I make An Entry Accept Decimal Numbers ONLY*

python
tkinter
programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of basic input validation on an `Entry` widget

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # register a validation function using the '%P' substitution code
        self.vcmd = (self.register(self.validate), '%P')
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(  # this is the entry you want to validate
            self,
            validate='key',  # trigger validation on a keypress
            validatecommand=self.vcmd  # set registration
       )
       self.entry.pack()

    def validate(self, P):  # P is the text being entered at the time of callback
        # this function should return True if the input is valid, or False otherwise
        return P.isdecimal() or P == ''  # include "or P == ''" to allow empty values


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()  # run the app
```

There's a lot more information about this available [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-validation/). I recommend reading through that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isdecimal() function to check if its decimal or not.
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isdecimal-method/#:~:text=Python%20String%20isdecimal()%20function,decimal%2C%20else%20it%20returns%20False](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isdecimal-method/#:%7E:text=Python%20String%20isdecimal()%20function,decimal%2C%20else%20it%20returns%20False).

Comment: thank you and for geekforgeeks  i use it in entry with validate and validate command and I use isdecimal in it